# How to get complete url from document.referrer when there are some special characters in it?

Tags: javascript, document, referrer

How can I get the complete url like "http://twitter.com/#!/larrickchen" using something like document.refrerrer if it did come from "http://twitter.com/#!/larrickchen" ??
document.referrer only return "http://twitter.com/" instead of full path. I guess special characters(#!) make this happened.
Does anyone know how to deal with it???
Edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer):

> A *dereferrer* is a means to strip the details of the referring website from a link request so that the target website cannot identify the page which was clicked on to originate a request.

From twitter, as far as I have seen in Firefox, the actual HTTP request headers are as follows:

> **Host**:    www.google.com
>
> ...
>
> **Referer**:    http://twitter.com/

Even though I came from http://twitter.com/#!/nytimes.  Twitter ensuring user privacy by not exposing the specific page a user came in from.  Without controlling the content on twitter.com, you won't be able to get the complete referring URL.  Sorry.